# How do nest products use weave to talk with each other?

Tags: nest-api

https://nest.com/press/nest-introduces-nest-weave-creating-most-comprehensive-developer-platform-for-the-home/

Nest Weave – Developed by Nest and previously used in only Nest products, this communication protocol lets devices talk directly to each other and to Nest products.

https://developer.nest.com/documentation/weave/weave-overview/

IPv6

---

Before the connection is established,

If there are two nest products, how does A-product get B-product's IP address ?

or B-product's any information ?

---

Any advice would be greatly appreciated